# How to start google chrome with run command?

Tags: google-chrome

I tried opening google chrome by typing "chrome" into the run command(windows + R), but it does not open.

Comment: Have you tried the command: `start chrome`    on the command line?

Comment: Did you add it to your path??

Answer (score 4):

You can just type **start chrome** onto your cmd prompt to start chrome from command line

Answer (score 1):

goto environment variables

```
This PC->Properties->Advanced System Settings (on left pane) -> environment variables-> new
```

and type "chrome" (without quotes) in variable name and

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

in variable value as below
[image]
Click Ok and close the windows.

That's it.
Press Window key+R
and type "chrome" (without quotes) and hit enter. 
Chrome will open